# Unable to run a react native apps by docker container

Tags: react-native, docker

I am trying to dockerize react native app but can't do.When i am running `docker-compose build` command it shows following issues.
[image]

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/android-studio: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install android sdk
RUN apt-get install -y snapd
RUN snap install android-studio

WORKDIR /node

RUN npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli
RUN npm install -g --force react-native

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]

RUN npm install -f --silent
```

**Compose file:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pd_rn:
    build:
      context: .
    command: ["react-native", "start"]
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - ./:/node
```

Comment: https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/
maybe this would help

Comment: You don't seem to have included in your question what the actual issue is.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual error?  Running GUI applications in Docker is finicky and non-portable at best, and you don't seem to be using the Docker image or network systems at all; would it make more sense to run the application directly on the host, without Docker?

Comment: Maybe try installing android studio not as a snap

Comment: I have been trying several way but can't install android studio. Snap is being installed successfully but when trying to install android studio it throws following erors`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/android-studio: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It can be fixed by:

```
sudo service snapd start
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
```

Now snapd should work correctly.
You could now write:

```
sudo snap install android-studio
```